# Is it possible to manually update the build variable $(Build.BuildId)

Tags: azure-devops

I am helping a friend with their VSTS build and we are using both build identifiers

- $(Build.BuildId)
- $(Build.BuildNumber)

This is specific to a Xamarin.iOS build where we are using the new VSTS Build tasks for updating the Info.Plist. We need to use the $(Build.BuildId) for the version code which is just a number that increments. Then we want to use the $(Build.BuildNumber) for the actual Version Name. If was to format this into the build string it would look like this:

- `$(Build.BuildNumber)` = 1.0.0
- `$(Build.BuildId)` = 148
- Result = 1.0.0 (148)

The problem is we have already submitted our app to the app store with a larger build ID then what our current build is at. Instead of running the build X number of times to sync it up we would like to manually update the BuildId so we can start using this for our full workflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it’s impossible.

The predefined variable `Build.BuildId` value is unique to record echo build in the VSTS account.

Even you can change the value by logging command, but it can only work for the current build, when you queue next the build, the build ID will continue increased without any effect.

Such as current `Build.BuildId` is 148, even if you use the value to 100 by `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Build.BuildId]2148"` in a build, but when another build is queued, the `Build.BuildId` will be 149.

The work around is **using a user defined variable instead `Build.BuildId`**:

Add a user defined variable such as `custom.BuildId` and set the value with `($(Build.BuildID)+GapNumber)`.

Such as if the current `Build.BuildID` is 148, while the build ID you submitted in app store is 2148, so you can use the `custom.BuildId` with the value `($(Build.BuildID)+2000)`. Then use the variables `$(custom.BuildId)` and `$(Build.BuildNumber)` for your app.

[image]

For next build. The `custom.BuildId` value will be 1149.

Comment: This is a great workaround for now. I was speaking with Chris Patterson from Microsoft and he said there is a new feature coming early 2018 that supports incrementing with a seed number similar to how the BuildID works

Comment: any updates on this?  early 2018 is here and gone.  @AndrewHoefling

Comment: As far as I know the only other way is using the build counter in the answer below provided by @Felix. I believe that is only available in build yaml and not the classic editor (not 100% sure on that)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the [counter expression](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/process/expressions.md#counter):

`MyAppVersion    $[counter('my-counter-prefix', 500)]`

With MyAppVersion being 500, 501, 502...

> - This function can only be used in an expression that defines a variable. It cannot be used as part of a condition for a step, job, or stage.
> - Evaluates a number that is incremented with each run of a pipeline.
> - Parameters: 2. `prefix` and `seed`.
> - Prefix is a string expression. A separate value of counter is tracked for each unique value of prefix
> - Seed is the starting value of the counter
>
> You can create a counter that is automatically incremented by one in each execution of your pipeline. When you define a counter, you provide a `prefix` and a `seed`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to update `Build.BuildId` but you can set `Build.BuildNumber` as it is shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#build-commands) using logging commands:

```bsh
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]my-new-build-number"
```