# Devops YAML - set build name using expression

Tags: variables, yaml, expression, azure-pipelines, build-numbers

In a yaml build, is it possible to set the build name using an expression; it would be advantageous if I could match the release pipeline with the actual build id.

Example:

```
trigger:  
- master

variables:  
    major: 2  
    minor: 3  
    offset: 2000  
    bid: $[$build.BuildID -as [int] + $offset]

name: "$(major).$(minor).$(bid)"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [UpdateBuildNumber command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number) to dynamically set the name as part of a bash or PowerShell script.

For more details you can see [this blog post](https://blog.danskingdom.com/Custom-version-numbers-in-Azure-DevOps-yaml-pipelines/), but the gist of it is something like this:

```yaml
name: 'Set dynamically below in a task'

variables:  
    major: 2  
    minor: 3  
    offset: 2000

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set the name of the build (i.e. the Build.BuildNumber)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      [int] $buildIdWithOffset = ([int] $(Build.BuildId)) + ([int] $(offset))
      [string] $buildName = "$(major).$(minor).$buildIdWithOffset"
      Write-Host "Setting the name of the build to '$buildName'."
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildName"
```

Comment: Thanks @MouthOfMadness, I'm glad it worked. Would you mind marking this as the answer please :) It seems you upvoted it (or somebody did), but did not mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There's yet another way to set the build number without using the scripts. The advantage of this method is that the build name is set from the beginning, unlike the script that changes the original name during the build. And the sequence number generation is cleaner (see the $(Rev:r) piece that works only in the "name" property of the pipeline.

You must use the "format" expression instead of ($Variable) syntax, because the build name is created during the Compile stage when the $(Variable) syntax does not work yet. Otherwise the variables will not be evaluated and will go into the build name as $(Variable).

```
name: '$(buildNumber).$(Rev:r)'
variables:
  majorVersion: '1'
  minorVersion: '0'

  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:
    buildNumber: ${{ format('{0}.{1}',  variables['majorVersion'], variables['minorVersion']) }}
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
    buildNumber: ${{ format('{0}.{1}.PR-{0}', variables['majorVersion'], variables['minorVersion'], variables['System.PullRequest.PullRequestId']) }}
```

More about expressions here: [Azure Pipelines Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the MSDN reference. I finally found the crucial info that `${{ ... }}` is evaluated at compile time, so can only use static vars, but `$[ ... ]` is evaluated at runtime, so can use all the normal `$( ... )` vars. Sprinkling this on your sample above suddenly started working.

Answer (score 0):

The example won't work for syntax error.

You can check the MSDN doc [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) and there's no mathematical operations like summation provided.

A better work around would be quiting the offset:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  major: 2  
  minor: 3  
  #offset: 2000  

name: $(major).$(minor).$(build.BuildID)
```

This will return you the name as `2.3.101` for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I require the offset to publish to the Apple and Google store.  It's difficult to trace the build through the system when you've got a different buildId vs a publish ID.

Comment: Is it possible that you can use [counter expression](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/blob/master/docs/pipelines/process/expressions.md#counter). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47894722/is-it-possible-to-manually-update-the-build-variable-build-buildid) is a similar thread where you can check for more information.

Comment: No.  I attempted a similar strategy but the task to update a custom variable happens to late in the process (in steps rather than declaration) to Name the build.

Comment: Yes. The build name is always generated before any of its tasks start running. As i mentioned, this seems not possible at current time.

Comment: Either an declaration expression or a pre-task would have been ideal.

Comment: This requirement to change buildname seems very useful and the function should be provided in future updates, but not possible nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the use the generated expression to automatically increment the `counter` function (which can only be used as part of a variable declaration) for each unique value, you can use the following:

```
jobs:
- job: VERSION_BUILD
  displayName: Version Build
  variables:
    - name: pipeline_start_date
      value: $[format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}', pipeline.startTime)]
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: generate_minor_version
    displayName: Generate Minor Version
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "Pipeline start date is '$(pipeline_start_date)'."
        [int] $minorVersion = [math]::floor(((New-TimeSpan -Start '2022-02-01' -End '$(pipeline_start_date)').Days) / 14) + 1
        Write-Host "Minor version is '$minorVersion'."
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=minor_version;isOutput=true;]$minorVersion"
- job: VERSION_BUILD_2
  displayName: Version Build 2
  dependsOn:
  - VERSION_BUILD
  variables:
    - name: minor_version
      value: $[dependencies.VERSION_BUILD.outputs['generate_minor_version.minor_version']]
    - name: major_minor_version
      value: $[format('{0}.{1}', variables['major_version'], variables['minor_version'])]
    - name: build_version
      value: $[counter(variables['major_minor_version'], 0)]
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Update Build Number
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        Write-Host "Major-minor version is '$(major_minor_version)'."
        Write-Host "Build version is '$(build_version)'."
        [string] $buildNumber = "$(major_version).$(minor_version).$(build_version)"
        Write-Host "Setting the name of the build to '$buildNumber'."
        Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildNumber"
```

This particular script calculates the `$minor_version` as the number of 2 week intervals (iterations) from a given point in time. So in theory, on every other Tuesday, the pipeline will increment the minor version of the build number by 1 and reset the build version of the build number to 0, which will then automatically increment for each subsequent build in that two-week period.

Comment: That's pretty cool; my issue was centered around a developer deploying a manual value of the version to the play store that exceed the value of the build id.  Example build id = 100, developer deployed = 6000; that's where I need to calculate an offset that took the build id and created a version that was: version id = offset + build id > 6000